# Customize push notification with a text, the user can choose

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification

i want to create a push-notification out of xamarin.forms, where the user can choose the text.
Like, the user want to get a reminder for something called "Dad's Birthday".

I have seen i can create push-notifications with firebase, where i can write down something, but i want the user to customize text to shown in the notification.

e.g.
User opens the app, create a new reminder called "Don't forget to drink enough!", set the timer for tommorow 4pm save it and close the app. I don't want to get a notification, only shows something standard for all like 'You have a reminder.'

Maybe there are other services except firebase they can do it?

Is there any way for it?

Comment: The contents of a push notification is **controlled by your server**. So, you need a server somewhere on the web. You'll need to write code on that server to keep track of users and what they want to be reminded about. All the app will do, is tell the server what text user wants, and when they want to be notified. The hard coding is all on the server. So isn't really a xamarin forms question.  It isn't even really a firebase question. As firebase intro says *"Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) provides a ... connection between **your server** and devices ..."

Comment: For your requirement you dont have to actually use the firebase firebase messaging instead. Use local push notification , in your case that best suits your requirement. Use firebase i.e remote push notificatoin only when you want some non user of the app to send the notification to the user of the app , it may be via another app or firebase console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For your requirement you dont have to actually use the firebase firebase messaging instead. Use local push notification , in your case that best suits your requirement. Use firebase i.e remote push notificatoin only when you want some non user of the app to send the notification to the user of the app , it may be via another app or firebase console.

[Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72925294/customize-push-notification-with-a-text-the-user-can-choose/73061604#comment128804998_72925294) from [krishnaacharyaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13431819/krishnaacharyaa)